# Improve speed, Python script to extract Gmail labels from messages

Tags: python, performance, gmail, gmail-api

I'm working on a Python script that exports every message ID present in my Gmail account along with their added labels (full label path) into a TXT file.

The script itself works, but the export speed is around 2 messages per second. For smaller accounts, this is fine, but for larger accounts, the export can easily take days, and in some cases, weeks.

Is there a way to increase the processing speed of the script, or is the limitation coming from Google itself?

```py
def get_label_path(service, label_id):
    label = service.users().labels().get(userId='me', id=label_id).execute()
    label_path = label['name']
    while 'parent' in label:
        label = service.users().labels().get(userId='me', id=label['parent']).execute()
        label_path = label['name'] + '/' + label_path
    return label_path

def get_message_ids_with_labels(service):
    profile = service.users().getProfile(userId='me').execute()

    page_token = None
    with open(OUTPUT_FILE_PATH, 'w') as output_file:
        while True:
            results = service.users().messages().list(userId='me', pageToken=page_token).execute()
            messages = results.get('messages', [])
            
            if not messages:
                break
            
            for message in messages:
                message_id = message['id']
                msg = get_message(service, message_id)
                headers = msg['payload']['headers']
                message_id = next((header['value'] for header in headers if header['name'].lower() == 'message-id'), None)
                label_ids = msg.get('labelIds', [])
                labels = [get_label_path(service, label_id) for label_id in label_ids]
                
                output_file.write(f"Message-ID: {message_id} - Labels: {labels}\n")

            page_token = results.get('nextPageToken')
            if not page_token:
                break
```

Comment: You could try batching it will save you some http calls

Comment: First get all messages into memory and then save it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe your goal is as follows.

- You want to reduce the process cost of your showing script.

In your situation, how about the following flow?

1. Retrieve label list as an object using [Method: users.labels.list](https://developers.google.com/gmail/api/reference/rest/v1/users.labels/list).
2. Retrieve all message IDs using [Method: users.messages.lis](https://developers.google.com/gmail/api/reference/rest/v1/users.messages/list).
3. Retrieve label IDs from message IDs using [Method: users.messages.get](https://developers.google.com/gmail/api/reference/rest/v1/users.messages/get). In this case, the batch requests are used.
4. Create result texts using the label list object and label IDs.
5. Write the result texts into a file.

When this flow is reflected in the modified script, it becomes as follows.

#### Modified script:

Please set `OUTPUT_FILE_PATH`.

```py
OUTPUT_FILE_PATH = "sample.txt" # Please set your output filename.
ar = []


def sample(id, res, err):
    # print(id)
    # print(err)
    ar.append([res["id"], res.get("labelIds", [])])


def get_labels(service):
    obj = service.users().labels().list(userId='me').execute()
    labels = obj.get('labels', [])
    labelObj = {}
    for e in labels:
        labelObj[e["id"]] = e["name"]
    return labelObj


def get_message_ids_with_labels(service):
    # Retrieve label list as an object.
    labelObj = get_labels(service)

    # Retrieve all message IDs.
    messageIds = []
    page_token = ""
    while page_token is not None:
        obj = service.users().messages().list(userId='me', pageToken=page_token, maxResults=500).execute()
        messages = [e["id"] for e in obj.get('messages', [])]
        messageIds += messages
        page_token = obj.get("nextPageToken")
    print(f"Total message IDs: {len(messageIds)}")

    # Retrieve label ids from message IDs.
    for i in range(0, len(messageIds), 100):
        batchIds = messageIds[i:i+100]
        print(f"Processing from {i} to {i + len(batchIds)}")
        batch = service.new_batch_http_request(callback=sample)
        for messageId in batchIds:
            batch.add(service.users().messages().get(userId='me', id=messageId, fields="id,labelIds"))
        batch.execute()

    # Create result texts using the label list object and label IDs.
    arr = []
    for e in ar:
        labelNames = []
        for f in e[1]:
            labelNames.append(labelObj[f])
        arr.append(f"Message-ID: {e[0]} - Labels: {','.join(labelNames)}")
    res = "\n".join(arr)

    # Write the result texts into a file.
    with open(OUTPUT_FILE_PATH, 'w') as output_file:
        output_file.write(res)
    print("Done")
```

- In this script, please call a function `get_message_ids_with_labels(service)`. `service` is a client for using Gmail API.
- When this script is run, a text file including `Message-ID: ### - Labels: ###` is created using the above flow.

#### Note:

- In this modification, it supposes that your client `service` can be used for using Gmail API. Please be careful about this.
- In my environment, 3,000 messages could be processed in about 1 minute.

#### References:

- [Method: users.labels.list](https://developers.google.com/gmail/api/reference/rest/v1/users.labels/list)
- [Method: users.messages.lis](https://developers.google.com/gmail/api/reference/rest/v1/users.messages/list)
- [Method: users.messages.get](https://developers.google.com/gmail/api/reference/rest/v1/users.messages/get)

### Added 1:

From your following reply,

> there is a huge speed increase. There was just one issue, as I need the "Message ID" from the metadataHeaders[]",

I couldn't notice that you wanted to retrieve the value of `Message-ID` in the header from your question. I thought that you wanted to retrieve the message ID of Gmail. In the case of the value of `Message-ID` in the header, how about the following sample script? The above sample script was modified.

#### Sample script:

```py
OUTPUT_FILE_PATH = "sample.txt" # Please set your output filename.
ar = []


def sample(id, res, err):
    # print(id)
    # print(err)
    ar.append([res["payload"]["headers"][0]["value"], res.get("labelIds", [])])


def get_labels(service):
    obj = service.users().labels().list(userId='me').execute()
    labels = obj.get('labels', [])
    labelObj = {}
    for e in labels:
        labelObj[e["id"]] = e["name"]
    return labelObj


def get_message_ids_with_labels(service):
    # Retrieve label list as an object.
    labelObj = get_labels(service)

    # Retrieve all message IDs.
    messageIds = []
    page_token = ""
    while page_token is not None:
        obj = service.users().messages().list(userId='me', pageToken=page_token, maxResults=500).execute()
        messages = [e["id"] for e in obj.get('messages', [])]
        messageIds += messages
        page_token = obj.get("nextPageToken")
    print(f"Total message IDs: {len(messageIds)}")

    # Retrieve label ids from message IDs.
    for i in range(0, len(messageIds), 100):
        batchIds = messageIds[i:i+100]
        print(f"Processing from {i} to {i + len(batchIds)}")
        batch = service.new_batch_http_request(callback=sample)
        for messageId in batchIds:
            batch.add(service.users().messages().get(userId='me', id=messageId, format='metadata', metadataHeaders=['Message-ID']))
        batch.execute()

    # Create result texts using the label list object and label IDs.
    arr = []
    for e in ar:
        labelNames = []
        for f in e[1]:
            labelNames.append(labelObj[f])
        arr.append(f"Message-ID: {e[0]} - Labels: {','.join(labelNames)}")
    res = "\n".join(arr)

    # Write the result texts into a file.
    with open(OUTPUT_FILE_PATH, 'w') as output_file:
        output_file.write(res)
    print("Done")
```

- When this script is run, the value of `Message-ID` in the mail header and the labels are retrieved.

### Added 2:

About your following reply,

> But I received this error "line 40, in sample ar.append([res["payload"]["headers"][0]["value"], res.get("labelIds", [])]) ~~~^^^^^^^^^^^ TypeError: 'NoneType' object is not subscriptable". I assume it is related to messages without label. I assumed when there is no label the output would be "... - Labels: "

In this case, please modify the above script as follows.

#### From:

```
def sample(id, res, err):
    # print(id)
    # print(err)
    ar.append([res["payload"]["headers"][0]["value"], res.get("labelIds", [])])
```

#### To:

```
def sample(id, res, err):
    # print(id)
    # print(err)
    labelIds = res.get("labelIds", [])
    if "headers" not in res["payload"] or res["payload"]["headers"] is None or len(res["payload"]["headers"]) == 0 or "name" not in res["payload"]["headers"][0] or res["payload"]["headers"][0]["name"] != "Message-ID":
        ar.append(["No Message-ID", [] if labelIds is None else labelIds])
    else:
        ar.append([res["payload"]["headers"][0]["value"], [] if labelIds is None else labelIds])
```

Comment: Thanks, for the adjustment, yes there is a huge speed increase. There was just one issue, as I need the "Message ID" from the metadataHeaders[]", I adjusted the code a bit, but this brings two more problems. See my answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/77751773/7607340

Comment: @x0100 Thank you for replying. From your reply, I didn't notice that you wanted to retrieve the value of `Message-ID` in the mail header. I apologize for my poor English skill. So, I added one more sample script. Please confirm it. I guess that the 1st sample script might be also useful for the users. So, I leave it. If I misunderstood your expected value, I apologize again. By the way, please remove your answer. Unfortunately, that is not the answer to your question.

Comment: Thx, now the correct Message ID is fetched. But I received this error "line 40, in sample
    ar.append([res["payload"]["headers"][0]["value"], res.get("labelIds", [])])
               ~~~^^^^^^^^^^^
TypeError: 'NoneType' object is not subscriptable". I assume it is related to messages without label. I assumed when there is no label the output would be "... - Labels: "

Comment: @x0100 Thank you for replying. And, I apologize for the inconvenience. From your reply, I added a modification point to my answer. Please confirm it. If that was not useful, I apologize again.

Comment: Thanks for the update. Now the script runs nice and smooth. There is just one hiccup, it looks like the script is too fast. I got the following error: ["Quota exceeded for quota metric 'Queries' and limit 'Queries per minute per user' of service 'gmail.googleapis.com' for consumer 'project_number:xxxxxxxxxxxx'.", 'domain': 'usageLimits', 'reason': 'rateLimitExceeded']. I added a 1.4 sec delay to the batch function but maybe you have a more elegant solution. I'm also not really sure that the request limit is 250/sec or 15k/min or even 12k/min.

Comment: @x0100 Thank you for replying. From `Thanks for the update. Now the script runs nice and smooth.`, I understood that your issue was resolved. About your new question of `rateLimitExceeded`, unfortunately, I cannot know your current script from `I added a 1.4 sec delay to the batch function but maybe you have a more elegant solution.`. And, I cannot replicate your situation. But, how about putting `time.sleep(10)` just after the line of `batch.execute()`? Please adjust `10` to your actual situation.

Comment: @x0100 If the same error occurs even when that modification is reflected, please try it after 1 day, again. Unfortunately, when I tested my proposed script, no error occurred. I deeply apologize for this situation. But, at least, I confirmed that from your reply, my proposed script works without your previous 2 issues.

Comment: Perfect. This is what I have in place right now and it works "time.sleep()". I was just in doubt if it was the correct way to go. Thanks a lot for all your support.